# Is it possible to queue songs on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I would like to queue up songs on my iPhone like I can on my desktop music player. Is this possible with iTunes, or is there an alternative music app that will let me do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an [on the go playlist](http://artoftheiphone.com/2008/10/07/how-to-make-an-on-the-go-playlist-on-the-iphone/) directly on the iPhone that acts like a queue. Alternatively you could [create a playlist](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/how-to-create-playlists-in-itunes/) in iTunes then import that to the iPhone by dragging the list to the phone icon. Any missing tracks would be imported.

Comment: The problem is that I want to queue up songs on the fly. I will check out on the go playlists however

Comment: @Casebash: This is the only way to do it.

Comment: This actually works pretty well. Songs added are added to the end and you can easily clear it